# My function is unable to find an object that I am assigning a value beforehand

Tags: r

I wrote the following function, which includes two other functions that I already wrote.

```
play <- function(){
  got_symbols <- get_symbols()
  print(got_symbols)
  score()
}
```

When I run play() it messages me with "Error, in "unique(got_symbols)", object got_symbols not found". I wrote score() such that it doesn't take any arguments, but uses got_symbols in its body (I don't think it's content matter but I'll show it to you guys just in case).

```
score <- function(){
  if ( length(unique(got_symbols)) == 1 ) {
    prize <- prizes_triple[[unique(got_symbols)]]
  } else {
    if (all(got_symbols %in% c("BBB", "BB", "B"))){
      prize <- 5
    } else {
      C_count <- as.character(sum( got_symbols == "C" ))
      prize <- C_prizes[[C_count]]
    }
  }
  DD_count <- sum( got_symbols == "DD")
  prize*(2^DD_count)
}
```

I don't understand why this happens, when I run play() it runs its code until it calls score(), which should search for got_symbols, but since it doesn't have it in its environment, it should go one up, and it should find the got_symbols that I previously assigned the value of get_symbols(), shouldn't it?
Now, when I put got_symbols as an argument in score(), it works just fine, but I don't understand what's the difference. I'll appreciate if someone can help me out with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following toy example:

```
foo <- function(){
  a <- 3
  bar()
}

bar <- function(){
  print(a)
}
```

When we run `foo()` we get:

```
> foo()
Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found
```

This is the behavior you're seeing. R's scoping rules distinguish between three kinds of variables: formal parameters, local variables and free variables, as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Scope).

In this toy example, `a` is a free variable in the function `bar`. This means that R will first look for a value of R in the environment in which the function was created. This is a subtle and often confusing fact, which is called "lexical scoping".

The function `bar` was created in the global environment, so that is where R looks first (and then the search ends with failure).

Compare with this:

```
foo <- function(){
  bar <- function(){
    print(a)
  }
  a <- 3
  bar()
}
```

Now `bar` was created in an environment (the function `foo`) so that's where R looks first, and in that environment, `a` exists:

```
> foo()
[1] 3
```

Comment: I understand now, my function was created in the global environment. I was confused because I thought it had created its own environment inside the other functions. Many thanks!